# For loop, then after each iteration, update result of "async/await"

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, async-await

After a loop, how can I update the result of "await" block?

EX:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       let thing = await ( foo => {
       return thing;     // thing returns 15.
    });

   for (let j = 0; i < thing; i++){
       //will loop 15 times the first time (out of 5 times because of outer loop)
       //want to change value of thing to 9, so the next time it loops 9 times
   }
}
```

**After the inner loop, I was expecting the flow to go back up to await block and re-evaluate the value or execute.** But this doesn't seem to be happening because the return value isn't changing.

I want **thing** to return 15 the first time, then loop 15 times. During the next iteration of the outer loop, I want **thing** to return 9, so the inner loops 9 times.

Edit: sorry everyone this was written correctly and the issue was from another part of code. Thanks for helping!

Comment: when you are reassigning a value to `thing` in your inner loop, you are probably updating your scoped `thing` (declared with `let`), which will be recreated after each outer iteration. I assume you have a `thing` variable in outer scope which are equals 15 in beginning of your code, if so, you will not able to change it this way.

Comment: You are `await`ing a function expression. That makes no sense. Is this your real code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a function here:

```
await ( foo => {
   return thing;     // thing returns 15.
});
```

but you never actually call the function. You could call it with something like:

```
await ( foo => {
   return thing;     // thing returns 15.
})()
```

…but it's really hard to understand why you are creating a function just to return a value.

Also, in your second for loop, you are defining `j` but then comparing and increasing `i`. That's hard to reason about and I think it might be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

you are just defining a function and not calling it. And also the `j` loops looks suspicious

```
let thing = await ( foo => {
  return thing;     // thing returns 15.
})();
```

I think this is what you were trying to do. Not entirely sure though

```
let thingArr = [15,9]
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){

   let thing = await ( foo => {
     return thingArr[i];     // thing returns 15.
   })();

   for (let j = 0; j < thing; j++){
       //will loop 15 times the first time (out of 5 times because of outer loop)
       //want to change value of thing to 9, so the next time it loops 9 times
   }
}
```